# BIOS update is blocked on this device

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bios

I have HP, Windows 10.  HP support utility tells me that a BIOS update is available and Windows 10 update utility tells me that no update is available. I don't know which one to trust.

If I try to update the bios, I get

> "BIOS update is disabled on this device".

What should I do?

Comment: Windows update wouldn't cover a bios update, so that would be why it doesn't see it. The update may be prohibited by corporate policy - though we don't know the circumstances of the machine in question.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you need more info in order to fix the problem?

Comment: well, in order for someone to - knowing if it's blocked by corporate policy or if it's just a home machine may help someone figure out what's preventing it, but it's not really my area of expertise.

Comment: You only trust HP for bios update. Windows never pushes bios update. Also, if you do t have a problem relating to bios you don't need to update it.

Comment: BIOS updates are not placed on Windows Update for obvious reasons.  [Doing research on problem before you ask it is always important.](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/The-bios-update-is-blocked-on-this-device/td-p/5300373)

Comment: HP forums are full of bricked bios's after trying to upgrade them, I don't Ever recommend updating the bios on an HP unless it is to solve a critical problem that cannot be solved any other way, updating the bios is high risk.

Comment: @Moab fine, won't update it then, anyhow i can't even if i wanted to!